# how to make 2 recyclerView beside each others using firebase UI?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

**hi** I am using **Firebase recyclerview  UI** and I succeed to perform one RecyclerView, but when I continue to add the second, the application creates error.

The question is how to add 2 recyclers in the same activity with very simple form? I just want them beside each others.

How can I do that?
this is my code

```
public class HarvestingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView T;
    RecyclerView S;
DatabaseReference mRefTot;
DatabaseReference mRefSin;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_harvesting);

    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    assert currentUser != null;


    T = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewT);//this is for total 
    T.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    T.setHasFixedSize(true);

    S = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewS);//this is for single 
    S.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

     S.setHasFixedSize(true);


    mRefTot = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("HarvestingActivity")
            .child("TotalActivity");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TotalUsers, TotalUsersHolder> T_Adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TotalUsers, TotalUsersHolder>(
            TotalUsers.class,
            R.layout.h_item_user_total,
            TotalUsersHolder.class,
            mRefTot

    ) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(TotalUsersHolder viewHolder, TotalUsers model, int position) {
            FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            assert currentUser != null;

            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
        }
    };
      mRefSin=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("HarvestingActivity")
            .child("SingleActivity");
             FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SingleUser,SingleUserHolder> 
            S_Adapter=new 
              FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SingleUser,SingleUserHolder>(
            SingleUser.class,
            R.layout.h_item_users_single,
            SingleUserHolder.class,
            mRefSin
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(SingleUserHolder viewHolder, 
        SingleUser model, int position) {
            FirebaseUser currentUser = 
         FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            assert currentUser != null;
            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());

        }
    };
    T.setAdapter(T_Adapter);

    S.setAdapter(S_Adapter);

}

public static class TotalUsersHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View view;

    public TotalUsersHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView Harvester_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.HarvesterName);
        Harvester_Name.setText(name);
    }
}
private class SingleUserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View sview;
    public SingleUserHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        sview=itemView;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView Answer_Name = (TextView) 
     sview.findViewById(R.id.AnswerName);
        Answer_Name.setText(name);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Would you mind sharing the crash?

Comment: thanks, I solved the problem and works perfectly